# Is there a significant difference in meaning between "I would like it to be" and "I wish it were"?

Tags: sentence-choice

What is the difference in meaning betweeb the following sentences.

> I would like it to be already 8 pm so that I could go home.
>
> I wish it were already 8 pm so that could go home.

Does the first sentence even sound natural?

Answer (score -2):

No.

`Wish` is slightly better English; but, the meaning of the two sentences are identical.  While some regions of the United States think of `wish` as a stronger version of `would like`, other regions don't.

The last sentence sounds better because it uses highly descriptive words.  Highly descriptive words are part of what makes English both a difficult language to learn, and a beautiful language to master.

Compare

> Her ochre skin glistened in the midsummer heat

with

> Her brownish, reddish, yellow skin shined wetly in the middle part of summer's heat.

They both same the same thing, but one sounds like a person is working a lot harder to say it.

Comment: You contradict yourself.  If some regions think there is a difference, then there is a difference.  Are you saying everyone in these regions is wrong?  I think you make a good point, but this answer needs a lot of work.

Comment: @Andrew if there's a difference in New York and New Jersy but not a difference in California and Arizona then "some regions think there's a difference, and other regions don't"  It's not a contradiction, but an observation that the world in general doesn't agree if there is a difference.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with making observations, but this one contrasts with the definitive "no" that begins your answer.   As written you're basically saying the people in those regions don't speak English in a way you approve.  Henry Higgins is fine for satire, but answers here should be less opinionated.

Comment: @Andrew As I lived in the mentioned places, it has nothing to do with what I approved of, but more to do with how I adapted to fit into my new homes.  I'm no Henry Higgins, even though the book was enjoyable.  I was only trying to point out that there isn't a consensus, and there are strong opinions that are contrary.  Myself, having to live in both of these worlds, I don't have an particularly strong opinion.  I really meant it is slightly better only because the word "wish" is a richer description, while "really would like it if" would be equivalent, if less concise.